# Shift Tab not showing the documentation of a command in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to see the documentation for a particular function on Jupyter and it is not working.

Example
if I say name = "hello world"
then call name.split(shift+tab), I get the documentation

Now when working with dataframes, I have imported numpy as np and pandas as pd
when I say pd.DataFrame(shift+tab) I get the documentation

When I say df = pd.DataFrame(data)
then try call df.dropna(shift+tab) I am not seeing the documentation

Why is the shift+tab being selective on when to show documentation ?

Comment: I don't know why this happens, but in past experience, running the cell first with shift+enter and then going back into the cell will usually allow shift+tab to show the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it seems like `jedi` is a culprit. I had the same issue, then read somewhere that uninstalling it would help, and it did.
Try:

```
pip uninstall jedi
```

and try again.